# How to index Dataframe or Index Including(!) the upper limit? (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, slice

Lets say I you have a Dataframe df filled with a Timedata-Index.

Now I need to slice this dataframe from Time A to Time B including B (==the row of the upper limit).

Now I know I can get it by this.

```
df = df[A:]
```

But the problem in my case is, that B **CAN** be the end, but in some cases it also **can NOT** be the end.

How can I do this? (indexing, with including the row at B)

```
df2 = [A:B] # including(!) the row at B
```

Comment: Can you please share a sample input with expected output.

Comment: 1st check if B is end, then proceed..

Comment: This could be a simplistic approach, but how do I get the next value after that if B is not the end?